# MySQL custom select

Tags: mysql, select

I have a single table with multiple columns and rows.  I have an id field for uniqueness, and I have another field that groups rows together with a group id.  Whenever a user chooses there group it sets the group id in column 1.  I'm trying to Select * from table where group id equals whatever group id is set in id 1.  Any help would be appreciated.

My table has id 1-200, a user field 1 (user input text), user field 2 (user input text), user field 3 (user input text), a group identification (user input text).  I have a button that is named after the group ID, when the button is pushed, it pulls the text fields with that group ID.  ID 1 is a call fill, if they choose say group ID "TEST" it will set ID 1 group ID to "TEST"  and it will show the user all data with a group ID of "TEST".  I am working on an update that will look at the Selected data and if anything has CHANGED it will change that one item.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Select * from table where groupid = '$groupid' and id = 1 this is what I keep going to but I know it's wrong

Comment: Please add [edit] your code to your question.  You may also want to add your sample data set and the desired result.

Comment: @MattB, please show us the table schema.

Answer (score 0):

Might need more details, but let's say you already have the `id` of the user as 2:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE groupid = (SELECT groupid FROM users where id = 2)
```